# The Auth Middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

How can I edit the Auth Middleware such that it redirects to another route instead of the default login route when a user is logged in.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

Edit the file app/Exceptions/Handler.php add the following:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
        : redirect()->guest(route('ROUTENAME'));
}
```

Got it from here: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/800